# Php Regex: how to match repeated patterns

Tags: php, regex

given following text

```
bond0:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
eth0: 11329920252 12554462    0    0    0     0          0      3561 13072970332 12899522    0    0    0     0       0          0
```

I need to capture columns values. I thought something about these lines:

```
Regex: `(\w+):(?:\s+(\d+))+`
Php: `preg_match_all('/(\w+):(?:\s+(\d+))+/sim', $data, $regs)
```

But unfortunately it captures only first column.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => dummy0:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
            [1] => bond0:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
            [2] => eth0: 11329920252 12554462    0    0    0     0          0      3561 13072970332 12899522    0    0    0     0       0          0
            [3] => ip6tnl0:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
            [4] => lo: 51675995  100695    0    0    0     0          0         0 51675995  100695    0    0    0     0       0          0
            [5] => sit0:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
            [6] => tunl0:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 0
            [5] => 0
            [6] => 0
        )

)
```

Any suggestion? Thanks
`

====**EDIT**====
Just to be clear: i know that i could `preg_match` searching for `\d+` values or split the whole string in lines and run explode on the each line, but I'm interested in regex solution where I have first column as first member of resulting array(actualy forgot to put capturing braces in the first draft of question), and following columns with data, every line putted in it's dedicated array...

Comment: Using `explode()` here would also be a viable solution.

Comment: `$array = explode($var,"\t");` would do it for you

Comment: I would prefer not to use explode, for the reasons I've written in question update. Thx anyway.

Comment: i'll add my solution in a comment incase you didn't find the `preg_match` solution:
`<?php
$val = "bond0:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
eth0: 11329920252 12554462    0    0    0     0          0      3561 13072970332 12899522    0    0    0     0       0          0";
$arr1 = explode("\n",$val);
foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
 $exp = explode(":",$value);
 $ex = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',trim($exp[1]));
 $arr[$exp[0]] = explode(" ",$ex);
}
var_dump($arr);
?>`

Comment: Is the number of columns per row fixed? If not, you are asking for a variable number of captures, and only .NET can do that.

Comment: @MaveRick, answers do not belong in comments.

Comment: @PatrickEvans my answer is an alternative solution so it's just a suggestion not an answer because of that posted it as a comment

Comment: @MaveRick, it's still an answer and not a comment, all answers are alternatives. plus putting code in comments is ugly and unreadable.

Comment: @m.buettner let's say that number of columns is fixed.

Comment: @Alekc then just do `\w+:\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)...` as often as necessary for your fixed number. the number of captures you get is solely determined by the amount of parentheses in your pattern.

Comment: @m.buettner infact it's what I'm doing right now, my only concern is that's ugly as hell, wondered if there was a possibility for a clean solution :(

Comment: @Alekc with a single regex, no. With multiple patterns, explodes or a generated pattern, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use `preg_match` or `preg_match_all` at all?

```
$results = array();
foreach (preg_split("/\r\n|\r|\n/", $data) as $line)
{
    list($key, $values) = explode(":", $line);
    $results[$key] = preg_split("/\s/", trim($values));
}
```

This should work as long as there is no more than one `:` on every line. Seems to me like it's the shortest and fastest way to write this too.

Comment: Not what I wanted (and it seems that it's not possible to do otherwise), but I'm marking this answer as the most elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$data = explode("\n", $data);
$out = array();
foreach ($data as $d) {
    preg_match_all('/\s(\d+)/', $d, $matches);
```

Puts `$matches[0]` equal to an array of matches. You then want to add it to the array of rows:

```
    $out[] = $matches[0];
}
```

You now have an jagged array of lines and columns. So, to reference line two column four, you can go to `$out[1][3]`.

Comment: Why the brackets around the space?

Comment: Ah, not needed. Removed.

Comment: `array_map( 'trim', $matches[0] )` is better :)

Comment: It's smaller, but performance takes a hit from it. Foreach is faster and a bit more flexible.

Comment: this will match all the numbers into a single array. Unless the columns are a fixed length you won't know which number goes with which line.

Comment: Mmm.. maybe, but i just tested it on a large array now, `foreach` took `2.027s` and `array_map` took `0.591s`.

Comment: Hmm that's interesting, may have been optimized since I last looked at benchmarks. I'll update the answer.

Comment: `/\s(\d+)/`, will get the same results without needing to do a trim

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$subject = <<<LOD
dummy0: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
bond0:  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
eth0: 11329920252 12554462 0 0 0 0 0 3561 13072970332 12899522 0 0 0 0 0 0
ip6tnl0: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
lo: 51675995 100695 0 0 0 0 0 0 51675995 100695 0 0 0 0 0 0
sit0: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
tunl0: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
LOD;

$pattern = '~^(?<item>\w+):|\G\h+(?<value>\d+)~m';
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
$i=-1;
foreach($matches as $match) {
    if (isset($match['value']))
        $result[$i]['values'][] = $match['value'];
    else {
        $i++;
        $result[$i]['item'] = $match['item']; }
}
print_r($result);
```

You will obtain the format you describe in your EDIT.

Pattern details:

```
~               # pattern delimiter
^               # anchor for the line start (in multiline mode)
(?<item>\w+)    # named capture "item"
:       
|               # OR
\G              # force the match to be contigous from precedent
\h+             #
(?<value>\d+)   # named capture "value"
~m              # pattern delimiter, m modifier for multiline mode
```

Comment: That's an incredibly bulky way to do it.

Comment: @ConnorPeet: Not so "bulky" as you think, since the pattern is apply only once.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you are looking for `preg_match` solution but this is in case you didn't find any usefull answer

```
<?php
$val = "bond0:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
eth0: 11329920252 12554462    0    0    0     0          0      3561 13072970332 12899522    0    0    0     0       0          0";
$arr1 = explode("\n",$val);
foreach ($arr1 as $value) {
    $exp = explode(":",$value);
    $ex = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',trim($exp[1]));
    $arr[$exp[0]] = explode(" ",$ex);
}
var_dump($arr);
?>
```

results:

```
array (size=2)
  'bond0' => 
    array (size=17)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
      1 => string '0' (length=1)
      2 => string '0' (length=1)
      3 => string '0' (length=1)
      4 => string '0' (length=1)
      5 => string '0' (length=1)
      6 => string '0' (length=1)
      7 => string '0' (length=1)
      8 => string '0' (length=1)
      9 => string '0' (length=1)
      10 => string '0' (length=1)
      11 => string '0' (length=1)
      12 => string '0' (length=1)
      13 => string '0' (length=1)
      14 => string '0' (length=1)
      15 => string '0' (length=1)
      16 => string '0' (length=1)
  'eth0' => 
    array (size=17)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
      1 => string '11329920252' (length=11)
      2 => string '12554462' (length=8)
      3 => string '0' (length=1)
      4 => string '0' (length=1)
      5 => string '0' (length=1)
      6 => string '0' (length=1)
      7 => string '0' (length=1)
      8 => string '3561' (length=4)
      9 => string '13072970332' (length=11)
      10 => string '12899522' (length=8)
      11 => string '0' (length=1)
      12 => string '0' (length=1)
      13 => string '0' (length=1)
      14 => string '0' (length=1)
      15 => string '0' (length=1)
      16 => string '0' (length=1)
```